# I am not getting Design Window and Palette window in netbeans of javaFx

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javafx, javafx-2

I developed one application in swing, but i need to change in javaFX, when i create javaFx Application, JavaFX in Swing Application it not sowing design window and palette window, how can i get those windows. but in swing application of jframe i am getting those windows like below image.

How can i proceed to change my stand alone application of swing to javaFX which application i need to select in javaFX list. 
And how can i get those Design windows and palette windows ?

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkQip.png)

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there is no design and palette windows for JavaFX in NetBeans. You must download JavaFX Scene Builder and link it with your NetBeans. To link Scene Builder with your NetBeans:

1. From the Main menu, select Tools and choose Options.
   On the Mac OS platform, select NetBeans and choose Preferences from the Main menu.
2. In the Options window, click Java and then the JavaFX tab.
3. Specify the location of the Scene Builder installation folder and then click OK.

Then if you double click on .fxml in your project tab, scene builder should open and design windows should appear.

Comment: with out fxml can i develop design through Scene builder

Comment: You can develop without fxml, but Oracle do recommend FXML for layout definition over the Java API, and i think Scene builder only supports fxml

Comment: with out fxml can i develop design through Scene builder,because javaFx Application , javaFx preload, javaFX in swing Application the fxml file is not available, is it possible. how to modify my swing to JAVAFX application for this which type of project i need to select in this javaFx Application , javaFx preload, javaFX in swing Application.

Comment: @-thodgnir : thanks of giving reply and please suggest me for above comment

Comment: @epn I don't know why you don't want to use fxml. If you're using swing and javafx at the same time, you can still put any content in a [`JFXPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) including content loaded using a `FXMLLoader`. Note that Netbeans does not include a WYSIWYG UI designer for javafx and I'm not sure whether a tool exists that would allow you to design both swing and JavaFX integrated in it at the same time.... If you just don't like to use fxml - it's easy to translate FXML to java code.